# How to extract specific text in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

How do I get a specific text only like "LHS" or "RHS"?

Thank you for helping.

[image]

Comment: You want to use `LEFT` or `RIGHT` and probably `FIND`. See [this site](https://datatofish.com/excel-string-functions-left-right-mid-len-find/)

Comment: What do you mean extract it? If the cell contains RHS then say RHS else if it contains LHS then say LHS. Unless you're needing the index I don't see why you would complicate this.

Comment: Or you could just `REPLACE` RHS or LHS with empty string if wanting to rid it from the cell

Comment: Oops I meant `SUBSTITUTE` like this `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, " RHS ", " ")`

Answer (score 1):

Provided that there are no other 3 character combinations ending with `HS` you can use: `=MID(A1,SEARCH("?HS",A1)+1,3)`

If you want to be sure to only find `LHS` or `RHS` use: `=MID(A1,IFERROR(SEARCH("LHS",A1),SEARCH("RHS",A1))+1,3)`

(Change `A1` in the formula to the cell you like to search in)

Edit: Left out spaces in front and after search value to find result at end of beginning of text

Edit2: Added the spaces again, implementing Chris Neilsen's workaround:
`=MID(" "&A1&" ",IFERROR(SEARCH(" LHS "," "&A1&" "),SEARCH(" RHS "," "&A1&" "))+1,3)`

Comment: Thank you. I tried the formula and working perfect fine for middle sentence; however, there is an error if the RHS or LHS appears in front or end of the sentence. since cant find the values for it dues to no space in front or end of the string.

Comment: @Kaiser ^^^ then replace `A1` in the formula with `" "&A1&" "`

Comment: Ok, I removed the spaces, but then I recommend using the latter function.

Comment: And implemented Chris Neilsen's workaround in Edit2, because that's the nicest way.

Answer (score 0):

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=MID(A2,MIN(SEARCH({"lhs","rhs"},A2&"lhsrhs")),3)
```